# How to grok the message part of my log with .. and -

Tags: parsing, logging, logstash, logstash-grok

I have different bucket names in my ceph cluster but I can grok only the one which doesn't have any special character in the name.

So this one I can grok:

```
2021-07-06T13:57:38.036+0700 7feda336b700  1 beast: 0x7fedfbac36b0: 10.1.1.1 - - [2021-07-06T13:57:38.036349+0700] "PUT /streaming/asdasdasd/259/25945595/25945595_210706135800103522093.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 70689 - "aws-sdk-java/1.11.354 Linux/3.10.0-1160.25.1.el7.x86_64 OpenJDK_64-Bit_Server_VM/25.292-b10 java/1.8.0_292 scala/2.12.8" -
```

with this filter

```
%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:LogTimestamp}\] \"%{WORD:request_method} /%{WORD:bucketname}%{URIPATHPARAM:request} HTTP/1.1" %{NUMBER:httprespcode:int}
```

I can get what I want method, name, code, bucketname

But if the bucket name is like "some..thing"

```
2021-07-06T13:57:38.036+0700 7feda336b700  1 beast: 0x7fedfbac36b0: 10.1.1.1 - - [2021-07-06T13:57:38.036349+0700] "PUT /some..thing/asdasdasd/259/25945595/25945595_210706135800103522093.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 70689 - "aws-sdk-java/1.11.354 Linux/3.10.0-1160.25.1.el7.x86_64 OpenJDK_64-Bit_Server_VM/25.292-b10 java/1.8.0_292 scala/2.12.8" -
```

or "some-thing"

```
2021-07-06T13:57:38.036+0700 7feda336b700  1 beast: 0x7fedfbac36b0: 10.1.1.1 - - [2021-07-06T13:57:38.036349+0700] "PUT /some-thing/asdasdasd/259/25945595/25945595_210706135800103522093.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 70689 - "aws-sdk-java/1.11.354 Linux/3.10.0-1160.25.1.el7.x86_64 OpenJDK_64-Bit_Server_VM/25.292-b10 java/1.8.0_292 scala/2.12.8" -
```

I can't match.
What is the trick?

Comment: The `WORD` pattern you're using to grab the bucketname (with %{WORD:bucketname}) translate to `\b[a-zA-Z0-9_]+\b`, so won't grab any special characters. You can use the `USERNAME` pattern instead

Answer (score 0):

```
%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:LogTimestamp}\] \"%{WORD:request_method} (?<interface>/{0,1}[a-zA-Z0-9]*)(?<interface_version>/{0,1}[a-zA-Z0-9]*)/(?<bucketname>(([a-zA-Z0-9]|[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])\.{1,})*([a-zA-Z0-9]|[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]))%{URIPATHPARAM:request} HTTP/1.1" %{NUMBER:httprespcode:int}
```